# java servlet context listener does not start

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7, servlet-listeners

Under tomcat7, I used both `@WebListener` on the class and

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>helpers.MyListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

in web.xml. It starts on my localhost tomcat and runs fine, but not on tomcat7 on another server. No error message in the logs I added a static initializer to log it when it starts, but there's no logged message, so the listener is just not starting. Any tips?

Comment: or logging isn't configured properly ?

Comment: check if everything is the same on the other server

Comment: amm it should be started. but do one thing try to remove it once and try

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are trying to use tomcat 7 for Servlet 3.0 which includes annotations support. I am no servlet expert, I have just started learning servlets 3.0(especially). For annotations I came across this resource called [caucho technology](http://blog.caucho.com/2009/10/06/servlet-30-tutorial-weblistener-webservlet-webfilter-and-webinitparam/). This website helped me a lot to learn annotations. I encountered the same problem as yours.